# Tomcat web app slow when using SSL

Tags: ssl, tomcat, java

We have a JavaEE application at my work place that is running on Tomcat 9. The application is running fine on the server itself. But when any client try to open the application from his PC, the application is extremely slow and some components are not loading properly.

When we disable HTTPS and use normal HTTP, the application runs fine for all.

Below is the SSL setting for tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
                   keystoreFile="E:\APP\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.31-windows-x64\conf\keystore.jks" 
                   keystorePass="12345678"
                   keyAlias="tomcatssl"
                   />
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: If I had to guess: check the links generated by your application, they might have a hardcoded `http` instead of using `ServletContext#getScheme()`.